# Yesod Binary Unavailable

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal, yesod

I have installed the Mac OS X Haskell PLatform from here:

http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

```
 > which ghc
   /usr/bin/ghc
 > which ghci
   /usr/bin/ghci
 >cabal update
   -----
 >cabal install cabal-install
   -----
 >cabal install yesod
   -----
 >yesod init
   -bash: yesod: command not found
 >which yesod
 >ghc-pkg list
   ....
   yesod-1.2.5.2
   yesod-auth-1.3.0.4
   yesod-core-1.2.13
   yesod-form-1.3.8.2
   yesod-persistent-1.2.2.3
   yesod-routes-1.2.0.6
```

Why did cabal fail to create a yesod binary?
How do I fix this install? How do I check where yesod is installed to manually create a symlink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why did cabal fail to create a yesod binary? How do I fix this install?

The yesod binary isn't part of the [yesod package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod) anymore. Instead, it has been extracted into the [yesod-bin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-bin) package:

```
cabal install yesod-bin
```

The binary should be in `~/Library/Haskell/bin`, however, I'm not an OSX user.

Comment: Seems like OSX paths differ a little bit: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Mac_OS_X_Common_Installation_Paths#Executables

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that the recomended way to start with Yesod development seems to be using [Stackage Server](http://www.stackage.org/) as described in [Yesod quickstart guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart).